# SQL - Set certain columns to null based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table named `people` with various attributes

- first name
- last name
- age
- phone
- email
- address
- ...

I would like to make a query that will return all `people`, however, under a certain condition (a separate subquery) I would like for certain columns of the select statement to be set to null for redacting purposes.

So, say I have the basic query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, age, phone, address
FROM people;
```

Which would return a table similar to:

```
|first_name|last_name|age|phone|address       |
------------------------------------------------
|Joe       |Someone  |12 |123  |1234 Somewhere|
|Bob       |Other    |45 |982  |4321 Somewhere|
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    if(people.field IN (
        SELECT other_table.some_id FROM other_table WHERE other_table.field = 'is good')
    )
        age, phone, address
    else
        NULL
FROM people;
```

With the result I would like to have:

```
|first_name|last_name|age  |phone|address       |
------------------------------------------------
|Joe       |Someone  |12   |123  |1234 Somewhere|
|Bob       |Other    |NULL |NULL |NULL          |
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: What is your condition ? Please include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a lateral join:

```
select p.first_name, p.last_name, s.*
from people p left join lateral
     (select p.age, p.phone, p.address
      from othertable ot
      where ot.other_id = p.field
     ) s;
```

The subquery will return no rows if there is not a match -- hence all the columns will be `NULL`.  Otherwise, it will return the fields from `people`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to solve this by puting the subquery in a `LEFT JOIN` and then using `CASE` in the `SELECT` clause to set the output columns to `NULL` when needed :

```
SELECT
    p.first_name,
    p.last_name,
    CASE WHEN s.some_id IS NOT NULL THEN p.age     END AS age,
    CASE WHEN s.some_id IS NOT NULL THEN p.phone   END AS phone,
    CASE WHEN s.some_id IS NOT NULL THEN p.address END AS address
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN other_table s ON s.some_id = p.field AND s.field = 'is good'
```

The thing that you need to be careful about is the *cardinality of the join*. If several records in `other_table` match a single `people` record, then you will get duplicated output rows. To avoid that, one solution would be to use `SELECT DISTINCT`, or to turn on aggregation by adding clause `GROUP BY p.first_name, p.last_name, p.age, p.phone, p.address` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a solution based on `EXISTS` which will be able to support any kind on multiplicity in `other_table`.
Note: you usually want to "link" values from `people` with values from `other_table` by referencing the correct fields in the sub-query, which I have done for `first_name` and `last_name`.

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    CASE WHEN MyCondition THEN NULL ELSE age     END AS Age,
    CASE WHEN MyCondition THEN NULL ELSE phone   END AS Phone,
    CASE WHEN MyCondition THEN NULL ELSE address END AS Addess
FROM (
SELECT people.*, EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM other_table WHERE field = 'is good' AND first_name = P.first_name and last_name=P.last_name) as MyCondition
FROM people P
) MyTable
```

PS: in case you want to extend this to other DBMS, remember that some may not support `EXISTS(...)` at the place where I typed it (example of such DBMS: Oracle).
In such a case, you need to do a `CASE WHEN EXISTS(...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` instead.